# Issue after updating Facebook and Facebook gets update automatically

Tags: facebook

I have Realme Pro 2 (ColorOS 6 and Android 9). I updated Facebook from Play Store.

After update, the new version is Facebook 260

And the issue is:

[image]

Even I don’t this see option:
[image]

Then, I uninstalled and reinstalled Facebook and issue not resolved.

I downloaded previous version (250) and installed.

It’s okay and easy to use. Facebook 250 is working fine and I don’t want to update it. Auto-update is also OFF from Play Store. However, it gets updated automatically.

Pls let me know, 
how to resolve issue with new version or how to stop it to get updates automatically?

Thank is advance.

Regards
FewL

Comment: Moreover, I did Settings & Privacy --> Settings --> Media and Contacts --> App Updates --> Auto-Update Facebook. Will that work so that Facebook will not get updated automatically till the time I do not update it manually? 
And how to resolve issue after update?

Comment: If it has been updated, there's no way except to uninstall the app and manually reinstall an older version. Play Store always only installs the latest version.

Comment: As I explained, first I updated from Play Store. The updated version is 260. There is an issue with updated version. I uninstalled and downloaded previous version (250). The previous version is working fine. I disabled Auto-update from both Play Store and In-App (Settings & Privacy --> Settings --> Media and Contacts --> App Updates --> Auto-Update). However, Facebook is prompting to update the app.